# Flutter How to get WhatsApp profile picture on Android

Tags: android, flutter, whatsapp

I'm developing an application, and I want to help my users with the registration process.

Users are creating profiles, so I want to automatically fetch their default WhatsApp profile picture from Media.

Is that possible? Looking for an Android solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to files from whatsapp folder with:

Add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Request permission as shown below

```
await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
```

Then you can read any file and write to any location in Android (for example: `storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media`). But the problem with that is you won't be allow to upload apps in google play store using that permission.